# Does iCloud keychain stores FileVault passwords?

Tags: macos, icloud, hard-drive, filevault

My MacBook Air drowned today and it was connected to an external hard drive encrypted with FileVault. I can't remember password for it. Will new Mac sync that password from iCloud or is the encrypted partition lost?